# How should I start this Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ajax, embed

I want to create an app in Ruby on Rails that when a user pastes the link of a video, the thumbnail is embedded, and when the user clicks the thumbnail, the video is embedded with ajax. How should I start developing this functionality? I plan on using [Embedly](http://embed.ly/). My first question is how do I use it? I've read the documentation, but there are a bunch of different tutorials and I'm not sure which one to use. And specifically how do I get the thumbnail and the video? Also, should I have a separate model for both the thumbnail and the video? Or should the thumbnail be a field in the video table? What should I be storing in my database?

I would really, really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed.ly API gives you a pretty wide [range of options](http://api.embed.ly/embed?url=http://www.slideshare.net/stinson/easter-1284190). Thumbnail is also included in the return hash. All you need to do is capture the url your users paste, plug it into [this API url](http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=http://www.slideshare.net/stinson/easter-1284190&maxwidth=600&format=json), and parse the returned hash for the thumbnail image.

You can then easily use the [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery) to generate the embed link when the user clicks on the thumbnail.

```
$.embedly('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfamTmY5REw',
           {maxWidth: 600,
               elems: $('#element'),
             success: function(oembed, dict){
                        alert(oembed.title);
                      });
```

Note that in this function elems property is where you want your video to be embedded. oembed parameter contains the hash, which includes the thumbnail image link. So you can do everything in this one call. Embed the video as soon as the user pastes the link, and simply hide the embedded video until the user interacts with the thumbnail image.

You should probably save the thumbnail url as a field of the same model as everything else.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions though (I'm a programming noob). How do I "plug the url into the API url" to get the thumbnail? Maybe I should read up on how to use API's first? Also, the jquery code you posted is just for retrieving the embed code for the video, right? So I should just chain `.hide()` to the end of it, and then create an `onClick` method that hides the thumbnail and shows the video? Also should I directly install that plugin, because it seems like all you need is jQuery to use it...

Comment: And so you think I should save the thumbnail url in my db. Should I also save the html embed code?

Comment: Don't save the html code. That's going to be generated by jQuery. As far as how to hide it, you need to hide $("#element") it's embedding into. To get the thumbnail, just replace the YouTube url in the code above with the url your user pasted, and the thumbnail should be at oembed.thumbnail_url inside the callback function. You can then call your database with ajax to save it somewhere. I hope this helps!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "oembed.thumbnail_url inside the callback function?" Also, does this all take place in a separate .js file that is called by the form?

Comment: And right now I can't get the video to appear. I'm using `'@video.video_url'` instead of the youtube link, but I'm not sure if I have access to that variable in the application.js file.

Comment: You don't need to pass the variable to application.js. You can render the url somewhere in your html and scoop that using jQuery. After that, you can call  $.embedly().

Comment: then what do I pass to the url parameter in $.embedly()?

Comment: You pass the video_url, you just grab it using a jQuery selector from wherever you put the url in your html. (Please accept my answer now. Then put other questions into a new post. )